# Handling IFrame using Watir WebDriver

Tags: iframe

Wanted to know how do you handle iframe using Watir WebDriver.

I am trying to automate a SalesForce based app which runs in a console mode.
All the GUI elements of the web applications are within iFrames.

The issue we are facing is the automated tests run perfectly fine in case of FireFox but when we try to run the same scripts in Chrome (using ChromeDriver ChromeDriver 2.20) the user action of selecting links within iFrames are not being performed.

Any idea if this is an issue/bug with the Chromedriver 2.20 being used.

Thanks,Umesh